# Big issue with panel data analysis in R

Tags: r, panel, panel-data, random-effects

I have a major issue with panel data analysis in R. I am trying to do a pooled OLS, a fixed effects and a random effects model for my analysis. The dataset I use looks as follows (this is just an example, my dataset comprises over 2900 data):

```
Y      X1    X2    X3     X4     X5     X6     ID    Year
0,03   0     0     0,05   0,01   0,00   -0,03  1     2013
0,02   0     0     0,05   0,01   0,00   -0,03  2     2013
-0,01  1     0     0,01   -0,02  0,01   0,02   3     2014
-0,04  1     0     0,01   -0,02  0,01   0,02   4     2014
0,01   0     1     0,02   0,05   0,06   0,01   5     2015
-0,06  0     1     0,02   0,05   0,06   0,01   6     2015
0,08   0     1     0,02   0,05   0,06   0,01   7     2015
```

The variables `X1` and `X2` are dummy variables for the year 2014 and 2015. The variables `X3-6` are changes in macroeconomic factors. Since my data are yearly, those macroeconomic factors only change once in a year.

Whenever I try a pooled OLS model through

```
ols <-lm(Y ~ X1+X2+X3+X4+X5+X6, data=Panel)
summary(ols)
```

R says that `Coefficients: (3 are not defined because of singularities`. Those three variables are `X4-6`.

Moreover, I´m trying a fixed effects and random effects model through

```
 fixed <- plm(Y ~ X1+X2+X3+X4+X5+X6, data=Panel, index=c("country", "year"), model="within")
summary(fixed)
```

and

```
random <- plm(Y ~ X1+X2+X3+X4+X5+X6, data=Panel, index=c("country", "year"), model="random")
summary(random)
```

Unfortunately, R either says

```
duplicate couples (time-id)
Error in pdim.default(index[[1]], index[[2]] :
```

or

```
Error in plm.fit(formula, data, model, effect, random.method, random.dfcor, :
empty model
```

Could someone please help me solve this issue. I am already struggling with this problem for a while.

Greeting and I appreciate any help,

RI

Comment: You do not have a colum named "country". How can you apply a plm here? 
It seems that your "ID" column is the ID identifier. Following this you do no have a panel data set, as every ID is different. Here, you cannot apply panel regressions.
Moreover, you need to exclude X1 and X2 and use your "Year" variable as a factor instead: `ols <- lm(Y ~ as.factor(Year) + X3 + X4 + X5 + X6, data=Panel)`